# Regarding error An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am beginner with c#, when i execute my code it shows an error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code".

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

This is my Code :

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showdata();
        }

```
    private void showdata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=demo; database=demo; Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from demo, con");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "A network-related or instance-specific error...": This mean that you program cannot find your SQL server. Please correct your "server=demo" part of you connection string.

Comment: Do you have a server named "demo" on your network? A server, not a database.

Comment: Examine the connection string and compare with this page: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. Which SQL server version being used? The `Server` parameter usually contains local or remote server name (or IP address), also check on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cmd command is not correct.

change

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from demo, con");
```

To

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from demo", con);
```

Comment: Correct, but the error happens on the connection open, not on the creation of the command

Comment: Then it seems like Integrated Security is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help i appreciate the same. I got my answer from a friend, there was an @ missing in my query.

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=demo; database=demo; Integrated Security=True;");

After updating it i was able to see my data on browser.

But once again thank you for your help everyone.